# Как считать определённую информацию из файла и заменить её на другую?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как считать определённую информацию из файла, и заменить её на другую в **js** или **node.js**?

Допустим файл находится в `/src/test1/myfile.php`

**Содержимое файла:**

```
test1
test2,test3, renameme63
test, renameme64
test
```

Нужно открыть, прочитать, и заменить все - **renameme**(включая цифры) на **ok**

**Примечание:** точную надпись строки **renameme**, мы не знаем, в ней постоянно меняются значения цифр: `renameme44`, `renameme01`,... и.т.д.

Необходим пример.

Comment: Переходите на базу данных и все станет проще

Comment: @Mira - в моём случае это не допустимо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На *Node.js* это делается следующим образом:

```
fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile("test001.txt", "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);

    console.log("File content before replace:");
    console.log(data);

    var renameMe = "renameme";
    var re = RegExp(renameMe + "\\d{2}", "g");

    data = data.replace(re, "ok");

    console.log("File content after replace:");
    console.log(data);
});
```

Здесь регулярное выражение вида

```
renameme\d{2}
```

соответствуем всем вхождениям строки `renameme`, за которой следуют две цифры.

Если количество цифр неизвестно, но хотя бы одна из них должна быть, то регулярное выражение должно быть следующим:

```
renameme\d+
```

Однако, оба эти выражения найдут вхождение, в том числе, и ***внутри*** строки вида

```
SOME_TEXT__renameme22__SOME_TEXT
```

Если это не то, что надо, придётся изменить регулярное выражение, добавив к нему маркеры начала и конца слова (`\b`):

```
\brenameme\d{2}\b
```

Объект `RegExp` в данном случае строится следующим образом:

```
var re = RegExp("\\b" + renameMe + "\\d{2}\\b", "g");
```

Comment: Хотел добавить, что после `data = data.replace(re, "ok");` нужно вписать в файл новые данные с замененным значением: `fs.writeFileSync('test001.txt', data);`